# What happens when a compact fluorescent lamp implodes?

Tags: electricity

When a incandescent lamp implodes, the filament burns up and the current is interrupted.

Yesterday, a compact fluorescent lamp imploded and blew all the switches / fuses. I'm not sure if the same would happen with ordinary fluorescent lamps.

Can it be that the charge stored in the capacitor is released backwards? Is something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the control gear, there are a variety of designs for circuits for starting and running fluorescent tubes. I don't think any of them involve capacitors but there is likely to be an inductor that might cause a voltage spike when the circuit is broken. Normally, an implosion of the tube would not by itself cause a short circuit and so would not trip circuit breakers (surely you don't have quaint 20th C fuses)

Comment: No, the installation was done in 2006.

Comment: I don't see how an inductor could cause a spike. Could you explain that?